# How to add a sub parent class inside the parent class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I want to add a sub parent class to my parent class using jQuery.

Previously I've tried this:

```js
$('.my-parent').wrap('<div class="my-sub-parent"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-parent">
    <div class="child-items">1</div>
    <div class="child-items">2</div>
    <div class="child-items">3</div>
    <div class="child-items">4</div>
</div>
```

But this one inserts the class outside of my parent, not inside.

What I want to achieve is like this html structure:

```
<div class="my-parent">
    <div class="my-sub-parent">
        <div class="child-items"></div>
        <div class="child-items"></div>
        <div class="child-items"></div>
        <div class="child-items"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this achievable? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `wrapInner` function.

```js
$('.my-parent').wrapInner('<div class="my-sub-parent"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-parent">
    <div class="child-items">1</div>
    <div class="child-items">2</div>
    <div class="child-items">3</div>
    <div class="child-items">4</div>
</div>
```

For more resources.

https://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/